How to properly overlay a stacked barplot with the line graph?
I am trying to overlay a line graph with a stacked barplot. Individually, these components work well, but together, I am unable to get a clean image.
In my approach, I am trying to use the stacked barplot as the base, and the overlay the line-graph, but remove all the axis labels and tick labels. However, I am unable to do so very well.
Here is my code:
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.8}

\definecolor{red1}{HTML}{ed5e5e}
\definecolor{red2}{HTML}{f6afaf}

\definecolor{blue1}{HTML}{1980ff}
\definecolor{blue2}{HTML}{328af6}
\definecolor{blue3}{HTML}{6dabf7}
\definecolor{blue4}{HTML}{94c0f5}
\definecolor{blue5}{HTML}{c8def9}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[%
ybar stacked,%
legend style={at={(0.5,-0.2)},
anchor=north,legend columns=-1,
draw=none},
ylabel={Counts},
xlabel={Year},
symbolic x coords={2011, 2012, 2013, 2014, 2015, 2016,
2017, 2018, 2019, 2020, 2021, 2022, 2023},
xtick=data,
xticklabels={2011, , , , 2015, , , , 2019, , , , 2023}, % Labels corresponding to the ticks
]
% Adding zero values for missing years
\addplot+[draw=red1, fill=red1] plot coordinates {(2011,0) (2012,0) (2013,1) (2014,1) 
(2015,1) (2016,0) (2017,0) (2018,1) (2019,0) (2020,0) (2021,0) (2022,0) (2023,0)};%-1
\addplot+[draw=red2, fill=red2] plot coordinates {(2011,0) (2012,0) (2013,0) (2014,0) 
(2015,2) (2016,0) (2017,0) (2018,0) (2019,1) (2020,0) (2021,0) (2022,0) (2023,0)};%-2
\addplot+[draw=lightgray, fill=none] plot coordinates {(2011,1) (2012,0) (2013,0) (2014,0) 
(2015,1) (2016,1) (2017,2) (2018,1) (2019,1) (2020,0) (2021,0) (2022,0) (2023,0)};%0
\addplot+[draw=blue5, , fill=blue5] plot coordinates {(2011,0) (2012,0) (2013,0) (2014,1) 
(2015,3) (2016,1) (2017,2) (2018,1) (2019,1) (2020,0) (2021,2) (2022,0) (2023,1)};%1
\addplot+[draw=blue4, fill=blue4] plot coordinates {(2011,1) (2012,1) (2013,1) (2014,0) 
(2015,0) (2016,0) (2017,0) (2018,1) (2019,0) (2020,1) (2021,0) (2022,1) (2023,0)};%2
\addplot+[draw=blue3, fill=blue3] plot coordinates {(2011,0) (2012,0) (2013,0) (2014,0) 
(2015,0) (2016,0) (2017,1) (2018,0) (2019,0) (2020,0) (2021,2) (2022,1) (2023,0)};%3
\addplot+[draw=blue2, fill=blue2] plot coordinates {(2011,0) (2012,1) (2013,1) (2014,1) 
(2015,0) (2016,1) (2017,0) (2018,0) (2019,0) (2020,1) (2021,0) (2022,0) (2023,0)};%4
\addplot+[draw=blue1, fill=blue1] plot coordinates {(2011,0) (2012,0) (2013,0) (2014,0) 
(2015,0) (2016,0) (2017,0) (2018,0) (2019,0) (2020,0) (2021,1) (2022,0) (2023,0)};%5
\legend{-2, -1, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5}
\end{axis}
%
\begin{axis}
\addplot+[
    axis line style = { draw = none },  % Remove axis lines
    tick style = { draw = none },       % Remove tick marks
    xtick = \empty,                     % Remove x-axis tick labels
    ytick = \empty,                     % Remove y-axis tick labels
    tick label style = { font=\empty }, % Remove tick labels
    xlabel = {\empty},                        % Remove x-axis label
    ylabel = {\empty},                        % Remove y-axis label
    enlargelimits = false,              % No extra space around plot
    axis on top,                        % Plot on top of grid
    xticklabels={\empty},
    yticklabels={\empty}
] coordinates {(2011,1.128020)
(2012,2.428221)
(2013,3.463347)
(2014,4.177622) 
(2015,4.640999)
(2016,4.880365)
(2017,4.383102)
(2018,3.593877)
(2019,3.285900)
(2020,3.299805)
(2021,2.863833)
(2022,2.233919)
(2023,1.334244)
};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}

And here is the output that I am getting:

How do I align to the two graphs correctly and make it use the x-axis labels that was set for the stacked barplot?

Basically, the second axis environment options goes outside \addplot, not inside.  This also sets the axis limits (xmin,xmax,ymin and ymax) and scales the second axis to be the exact same size (possibly overkill).
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{xcolor}
%\pgfplotsset{compat=1.8}

\definecolor{red1}{HTML}{ed5e5e}
\definecolor{red2}{HTML}{f6afaf}

\definecolor{blue1}{HTML}{1980ff}
\definecolor{blue2}{HTML}{328af6}
\definecolor{blue3}{HTML}{6dabf7}
\definecolor{blue4}{HTML}{94c0f5}
\definecolor{blue5}{HTML}{c8def9}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
xmin=2010, xmax=2024, ymin=0, ymax=5,
ybar stacked,%
legend style={at={(0.5,-0.2)},
  anchor=north,legend columns=-1,
  draw=none},
ylabel={Counts},
xlabel={Year},
%symbolic x coords={2011, 2012, 2013, 2014, 2015, 2016, 2017, 2018, 2019, 2020, 2021, 2022, 2023},
xtick=data,
xticklabels={2011, , , , 2015, , , , 2019, , , , 2023}, % Labels corresponding to the ticks
]
% Adding zero values for missing years
\addplot+[draw=red1, fill=red1] plot coordinates {(2011,0) (2012,0) (2013,1) (2014,1) 
(2015,1) (2016,0) (2017,0) (2018,1) (2019,0) (2020,0) (2021,0) (2022,0) (2023,0)};%-1
\addplot+[draw=red2, fill=red2] plot coordinates {(2011,0) (2012,0) (2013,0) (2014,0) 
(2015,2) (2016,0) (2017,0) (2018,0) (2019,1) (2020,0) (2021,0) (2022,0) (2023,0)};%-2
\addplot+[draw=lightgray, fill=none] plot coordinates {(2011,1) (2012,0) (2013,0) (2014,0) 
(2015,1) (2016,1) (2017,2) (2018,1) (2019,1) (2020,0) (2021,0) (2022,0) (2023,0)};%0
\addplot+[draw=blue5, , fill=blue5] plot coordinates {(2011,0) (2012,0) (2013,0) (2014,1) 
(2015,3) (2016,1) (2017,2) (2018,1) (2019,1) (2020,0) (2021,2) (2022,0) (2023,1)};%1
\addplot+[draw=blue4, fill=blue4] plot coordinates {(2011,1) (2012,1) (2013,1) (2014,0) 
(2015,0) (2016,0) (2017,0) (2018,1) (2019,0) (2020,1) (2021,0) (2022,1) (2023,0)};%2
\addplot+[draw=blue3, fill=blue3] plot coordinates {(2011,0) (2012,0) (2013,0) (2014,0) 
(2015,0) (2016,0) (2017,1) (2018,0) (2019,0) (2020,0) (2021,2) (2022,1) (2023,0)};%3
\addplot+[draw=blue2, fill=blue2] plot coordinates {(2011,0) (2012,1) (2013,1) (2014,1) 
(2015,0) (2016,1) (2017,0) (2018,0) (2019,0) (2020,1) (2021,0) (2022,0) (2023,0)};%4
\addplot+[draw=blue1, fill=blue1] plot coordinates {(2011,0) (2012,0) (2013,0) (2014,0) 
(2015,0) (2016,0) (2017,0) (2018,0) (2019,0) (2020,0) (2021,1) (2022,0) (2023,0)};%5
\legend{-2, -1, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5}
\coordinate (corner) at (rel axis cs: 1,1);
\end{axis}
%
\path (corner);
\pgfgetlastxy{\bwidth}{\bheight}%
\begin{axis}[
xmin=2010, xmax=2024, ymin=0, ymax=5,
scale only axis, width={\bwidth}, height={\bheight},
axis lines=none, 
]
\addplot+ coordinates {(2011,1.128020)
(2012,2.428221)
(2013,3.463347)
(2014,4.177622) 
(2015,4.640999)
(2016,4.880365)
(2017,4.383102)
(2018,3.593877)
(2019,3.285900)
(2020,3.299805)
(2021,2.863833)
(2022,2.233919)
(2023,1.334244)
};
\end{axis}

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}


Explanation
In your code, you’re using two different axis environments:  one for the stacked bar chart, and another for the line graph on top of it. As a result, PGFPlots is creating two different axes for you as part of the same tikzpicture.
Because the first axis is the actual axis that you wanted to use, I deleted the second axis environment from your code so that all plots use the axis. Next, I added the stack plots = false key to the line graph, so that PGFPlots wouldn’t interpret your line graph coordinates as cumulative counts to be added onto the bar chart. This lets you place the line graph directly on top of the stacked bar chart while also including it from the stacked count itself.
Just so you know, when you were attempting to get the second axis to vanish, you passed your key values into the \addplot+ command rather than the axis environment. This is why the labels and ticks from your second axis wouldn't go away, though fortunately it helped you to catch this problem :)
Result

Code
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.8}

\definecolor{red1}{HTML}{ed5e5e}
\definecolor{red2}{HTML}{f6afaf}

\definecolor{blue1}{HTML}{1980ff}
\definecolor{blue2}{HTML}{328af6}
\definecolor{blue3}{HTML}{6dabf7}
\definecolor{blue4}{HTML}{94c0f5}
\definecolor{blue5}{HTML}{c8def9}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[%
    ybar stacked,%
    legend style={
        at={(0.5,-0.2)},
        anchor=north,legend columns=-1,
        draw=none
    },
    ylabel={Counts},
    xlabel={Year},
    symbolic x coords={
        2011, 2012, 2013, 2014, 2015, 2016, 2017, 2018, 2019, 2020, 2021, 2022, 2023
    },
    xtick = data,
    xticklabels = {2011, , , , 2015, , , , 2019, , , , 2023} % Labels corresponding to the ticks
]

% Moving this code upwards so that the line graph appears above the stacked bar chart
\addplot+[
    sharp plot,
    stack plots=false,
    color = blue,
    mark = *,
    fill = none
] coordinates {
    (2011,1.128020)
    (2012,2.428221)
    (2013,3.463347)
    (2014,4.177622)
    (2015,4.640999)
    (2016,4.880365)
    (2017,4.383102)
    (2018,3.593877)
    (2019,3.285900)
    (2020,3.299805)
    (2021,2.863833)
    (2022,2.233919)
    (2023,1.334244)
};

% Adding zero values for missing years
\addplot+[draw=red1, fill=red1] plot coordinates {(2011,0) (2012,0) (2013,1) (2014,1) 
(2015,1) (2016,0) (2017,0) (2018,1) (2019,0) (2020,0) (2021,0) (2022,0) (2023,0)};%-1
\addplot+[draw=red2, fill=red2] plot coordinates {(2011,0) (2012,0) (2013,0) (2014,0) 
(2015,2) (2016,0) (2017,0) (2018,0) (2019,1) (2020,0) (2021,0) (2022,0) (2023,0)};%-2
\addplot+[draw=lightgray, fill=none] plot coordinates {(2011,1) (2012,0) (2013,0) (2014,0) 
(2015,1) (2016,1) (2017,2) (2018,1) (2019,1) (2020,0) (2021,0) (2022,0) (2023,0)};%0
\addplot+[draw=blue5, , fill=blue5] plot coordinates {(2011,0) (2012,0) (2013,0) (2014,1) 
(2015,3) (2016,1) (2017,2) (2018,1) (2019,1) (2020,0) (2021,2) (2022,0) (2023,1)};%1
\addplot+[draw=blue4, fill=blue4] plot coordinates {(2011,1) (2012,1) (2013,1) (2014,0) 
(2015,0) (2016,0) (2017,0) (2018,1) (2019,0) (2020,1) (2021,0) (2022,1) (2023,0)};%2
\addplot+[draw=blue3, fill=blue3] plot coordinates {(2011,0) (2012,0) (2013,0) (2014,0) 
(2015,0) (2016,0) (2017,1) (2018,0) (2019,0) (2020,0) (2021,2) (2022,1) (2023,0)};%3
\addplot+[draw=blue2, fill=blue2] plot coordinates {(2011,0) (2012,1) (2013,1) (2014,1) 
(2015,0) (2016,1) (2017,0) (2018,0) (2019,0) (2020,1) (2021,0) (2022,0) (2023,0)};%4
\addplot+[draw=blue1, fill=blue1] plot coordinates {(2011,0) (2012,0) (2013,0) (2014,0) 
(2015,0) (2016,0) (2017,0) (2018,0) (2019,0) (2020,0) (2021,1) (2022,0) (2023,0)};%5
\legend{-2, -1, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5}
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}

